# NLS missing while accessing property file in eclipse plugin development

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I have written my property file at the same level of my /src folder and am trying to access the same .ls Bundlename path for my file.

error:

```
NLS missing message: key_one in: org.eclipse.core.utils.messages
```

code:

```java
public class Messages extends NLS {
  private static final String BUNDLE_NAME = "org.eclipse.core.utils.messages"; //$NON-NLS-1$
       
  public static String key_one;
```

I have added properties file in my build file as:

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               Message.properties,\
               META-INF/,\
               icons/,\
               .,\




  static {
    NLS.initializeMessages(BUNDLE_NAME, Messages.class);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the Message.properties file to the src folder under appropriate package.That should hopefully resolve the issue.